# Equivalent of keep interrupt?

Tags: assembly, interrupt, dos, low-level

I've heard about a keep interrupt in dos, apparently you can't kill that process normally with CTRL+C or CTRL+D. I was wondering whether operating systems these days have a replacement for it?

Comment: Can you give a link / reference to where you heard this?  "keep interrupt" isn't any kind of standard terminology that I know of, and it's not completely clear what it refers to.

Comment: On Linux, for example, you can set the terminal into "raw mode", in which the OS does no special handling of keystrokes like Ctrl-C and Ctrl-D and simply passes them as input keycodes to your program.  For Ctrl-C in particular you can also install a handler for the SIGINT signal.

Comment: @NateEldredge Being involved in 86-DOS programming I assume they're referring to the TSR (Terminate but Stay Resident) method of installing *resident* software. The "keep interrupt" then refers to DOS's interrupt 27h (or the more modern interrupt 21h service 31h). (A fun aside: [My TSRs](https://pushbx.org/ecm/web/#projects-tsr) use a different installation method, not the 21.31 service.) One equivalent would be daemons. Though I do not know of an equivalent for TSRs that, eg, want to display something on the screen / in a terminal from the background, like my lClock.

Comment: @ecm: Some TSRs took the brute force approach of stealing the keyboard or timer interrupts. They'd save the previous interrupt vector and pass along the events after they used them. That's why they had to be uninstalled in the order they were installed, because there was no way to remove them from the middle of the chain. It was messy (and rude).

Comment: If you're talking about TSRs, it's not special on a multitasking OS.  You just run something in the background, or have it fork/exec a child process and then exit.

Comment: @sj95126: There are ways to make TSRs that can be uninstalled in any order, but they need to cooperate somewhat. Chiefly there's [the IBM Interrupt Sharing Protocol](https://pushbx.org/ecm/test/20211110/intshare/INTSHARE.DOC) which you can use to advertise the downlink of your hook, and can also use to find the downlinks of other programs. There's also [the Alternate Multiplex Interrupt Specification](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/22212/are-there-any-other-historical-traces-of-the-earlier-versions-of-the-alternate-m) which specifies discovery methods for resident programs.

Comment: @sj95126: Putting them together gets you my advanced deinstallation method, described [in the KEEPHOOK manual](https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/tsr/keephook.htm#long-advanced). This allows to shuffle or uninstall handlers somewhat even when a non-cooperative program was installed subsequently.